# Does Design Automation API (Beta)v3 for Revit supports older version of Revit files like 2015/2016/2017?

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

Since DesignAutomationBridge.dll is available in 2018 & 2019 versions, and thus add-in will be in Revit 2018/2019. So does it support older version of revit input files like 2015/2016/2017?

I observed when run add-in locally: Revit engine upgrades the file first if it is in old version and then process as per our add-in logic. But while upgrading, it is showing **Model Upgrade** popup with Cancel Upgrade button. API doc says that it wont allow any UI related operation so will this **Model Upgrade** popup causing this job break/fail on forge platform?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Design Automation for Revit allows backward compatibility on Revit files. It would go through the same upgrade process that you experience in desktop Revit.

For handling failures during upgrade or even any transaction within your appbundles, you may refer the documentation:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/handling-failures/

Answer (score 0):

Model Upgrading will not break/fail the job by Design Automation for Revit, but there is no Cancel option during the upgrading as desktop Revit.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - We have a demo sample that makes use of Design Automation to upgrade older files:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-nodejs-revit.file.upgrader

Viewer and Model Derivative does not support old rvt files. It will be useful for viewing purpose as well.